# “is said to be” vs. “is said to have been”

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, perfect-constructions

Can we use both of variants and are they interchangeable?

> 1. The house is said to have been built a century ago.
> 2. The house is said to be built a century ago.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is the correct one.

Consider what you get by changing the phrase "is said to be" to a simple "is".  For the second sentence, you get

> *The house is built a century ago.

Which is not a valid statement.